# How to call ResolveCustomer and GetEntitlements from aws-marketplace using aws-sdk-go?

Tags: aws-sdk-go, aws-marketplace

I need to call ResolveCustomer and GetEntitlements services using aws-sdk-go. There is no code samples available on how to configure the aws clients for such calls.

Can someone help with the go code examples?

It will be helpful if someone has done unit testing for such calls; in terms of how to mock the ResolveCustomer and GetEntitlements API calls in golang?

Answer (score 0):

The MarketPlaceMetering package's New function, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/marketplacemetering/#New, has a short example of creating a MarketPlaceMetering client.

GetEntitlements is part of the MarketplaceEntitlementService package, so see that package's New function, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/marketplaceentitlementservice/#New, for a short example of creating a MarketPlaceEntitlementService client.

For more info on configuring the SDK, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/making-requests.html.

Note that these are both in the V1 version of the Go SDK. Feel free to browse the V2 version, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2, which has some differences in how you create a client (you should be able to figure it out from the DynamoDB example there).